# Transfer Data to a different Activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, checkbox

When I check a CheckBox I want the checkbox to be transfered to a differnet Activity and deleted in the previuos Activity.

Please Help me or lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you want to happen is that the **value** from the CheckBox is sent to the next Activity. To do this, send the value as an extra on the intent. E.g., in ActivityA:

```
final CheckBox checkBoxA = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_id_A);
...
boolean value = checkBoxA.isChecked();
....
Intent intent - new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("checkbox_value", value);
```

In ActivityB's onCreate() method:

```
final CheckBox checkBoxB = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_id_B);
boolean value = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("checkbox_value", false);
checkBoxB.setChecked(value);
```